# Google Geocoding: Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined at Object.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, geocoding

Hi I am using Google Geocoding to place a map marker on from a Json request results. Please see below code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function () {
        $('.table').hide();
        $.getJSON(url, '', function (response) {

                map.setCenter(JSON.parse(response[0].coordinates));
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: response[0].address
                });
                ;
                var ico = '/assets/images/address.png';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: JSON.parse(response[0].coordinates),
                    title: response[0].address,
                    icon: ico
                });


                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

        });

    })
</script>



<script>


    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-XXXXX, XXXXX);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

For some reason when I hard refresh my page or load the page for the first time I get the

```
Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined     at Object.success
```

error. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It's not clear from your code what the order of execution is. `map` doesn't get defined until `initialize` is called, but that's not included in the code. My hunch is that you are using `map` before it's initialized, but there's not enough code in your example to show it.

Comment: @Mark Meyer Here's my code that calls the map and I have placed it above all the above code `<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js??key=XXXX&callback=initialize"> </script>`